# Hibernate - Add orderBy() to DetachedCriteria if none is present?

Tags: java, hibernate, detachedcriteria

I'm trying to build a query on the fly from a custom query object.

At one point in the code, the orderBy may be added to a DetachedCriteria. Later down the line, I'd like to add an orderBy should none already exist in the DetachedCriteria. Looking through the docs, I can't seem to find any way to access this information.

Is there some way to do this?

(Of course if it's impossible, I'll just refactor my code around this)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

```
    DetachedCriteria detached; //intialized DetachedCriteria
    Session s; //intialized hibernate session

    //get the criteriaImpl executing the query 
    CriteriaImpl executableCriteria = (CriteriaImpl) detached.getExecutableCriteria(s);

    //return new iterator of the OrderEntries
    Iterator<CriteriaImpl.OrderEntry> orderEntryIterator = executableCriteria.iterateOrderings();

    //check if it has an order entry
    if (orderEntryIterator.hasNext()) {

    }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hm... I don't have access to the session at the point where I'm building the query unfortunately, so not sure this can work for my use-case. Good suggestion though!